# VSCode marks functions as undefined, because the include structure of my Project is odd

Tags: visual-studio-code, autoit

I am having troubles with the Problems-Feature of VSCode. The language of my code is AutoIt, but i think the same problem might occur when using other languages.

I have a structure in my Project, where I include a lot of files from my main file. Inside these files are functions which sometimes reference functions from other included files.
I included these lower level functions first, so the code compiles without problems, but it is still marked as false by VSCode, and it appears in the "Problems" section.

[func1() is marked as undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/519qF.png)

Because func1 from Folder1 is only indirectly included, it is also not available in the code completion.
What would be the best solution to solve these Problems? Thank you in advance

I already managed to get rid of the red icon in the Tabs above the editor by changing this setting:
"problems.decorations.enabled": false
but this does not change anything about the red underlining in the editor and the missing code completion so it doesnt fix anything...

I tried to find a fix for this problem on the Internet, but found nothing. Sorry if this question was already solved elsewhere.

Comment: instead of `#include <Folder1\functions.au3>` try `#include "Folder1\functions.au3"` ?

Comment: If any extensions are necessary to reproduce your issue, provide a link to their Visual Studio marketplace page.

Comment: or maybe try `#include ".\Folder1\functions.au3"`